# C# mongodb 2.0 Find and project ordered part of an array

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I have the following codeblock:

```
var r = this.collections.competitions.Find(filter)
                                             .Project(x => x.TeamRanks)
                                             .Project(t => t.Logo)
                                             .Sort(sort)
                                             .Skip(prev)
                                             .Limit(count)
                                             .Single();
```

I have this `Competition` collection which have 3 fields

```
Class Competition {
           public ObjectId _Id;
           public string Logo;
           public List<string> TeamRanks
}
```

The filter here is on the `Competition._Id`.
I want to get the Logo AND the first 5 ranked teams in a Rank ascending order.(Which are given by the `count` value)
The list might be huge so I want to use Project here (or an alternative solution with Fields) but it can't seem to work.
issues:

1.
 `r` is of type `string` which is the second `Project` and ignoring the TeamRanks.

2.
How can I only get the top 5 ranked teams in an ascending order?

TIA.

**EDIT**

I just now noticed that the entire sort, skip and limit are done on the competition, I want it to be applied on the TeamRanks of course.
So if, for example, the method receives count = 7 and some competitionId, the method need to return the competition with the provided id and inside it the top 7 teams ordered..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ObjectId _idFilter = new ObjectId();//you set your _Id filter to whatever you need
Competition _theCompetition = await __db.GetCollection<Competition>("Competiton")
    .Find(Builders<Competition>.Filter.Eq("_Id", _idFilter)).SingleAsync();
int _count = 5; //your chosen count
List<string> _orderedList = _theCompetition.TeamRanks
    .OrderBy(teamRank => teamRank).Take(_count).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Below is the code that gets the first five elements of the TeamRanks array in the returned document

```
var __projection = Builders<Competition>.Projection;
var _theCompetition = await __db.GetCollection<Competition>("Competiton")
.Find(Builders<Competition>.Filter.Eq("_id", _idFilter))                  
.Project(__projection.Include(x=>x.Logo).Include(x=>x.TeamRanks).Slice("TeamRanks", 5))
.SingleAsync();
```

Comment: This is so wrong. Im getting the entire document here, its what i want to prevent

Comment: you can sort the documents at the root level but sorting array elements when you do a find() is the challenging part. You may need to do an aggregation

Comment: I dont mind sorting it when entering it. Just need the method for getting the first five

Comment: just edited my answer to include code that uses projection with slice to get the first 5 elements of the array

Comment: Just to add -- the order of the method chaining on the projection does matter.  The slice will not work correctly unless called after the include statements.  Also the slice could have been written as '.Slice(x=>x.TeamRanks, 5)' instead of using a hard coded string.